# MySQL update table column based on another table columns values

Tags: mysql

I am using two codes and none is working

```
update articles set articles.wp_id = ( SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='_my_old_id' AND articles.id=wp_postmeta.meta_value)
```

and

```
UPDATE articles
   JOIN wp_postmeta
   ON articles.id = wp_postmeta.meta_value
SET    articles.wp_id = wp_postmeta.post_id;
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key ='_my_old_id'
```

Thanks

Comment: is there any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - semicolon should not be after set command

```
UPDATE articles JOIN wp_postmeta
ON articles.id = wp_postmeta.meta_value
SET articles.wp_id = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key ='_my_old_id'
```

Comment: The sql is taking too long. is there any way to make it better?